# VS Boilerplate error when creating a new Controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I'm migrating an app to an MVC version in a more integrated app.  I keep getting the following error when trying to add a new controller.  The erroring class is the same, despite trying with several different classes.  This happens when right-clicking the Controller dir and choosing 'Add Controller' and then choosing class Contact

```
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
Attempting to compile the application in memory with the modified DbContext.
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Contact'
The entity type 'GroupToContactLink' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943. StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
```

GroupToContactLink is a fairly basic entity linking class, and has a composite key.

```
[Table("Report_Link_Group_to_Contact")]
public class GroupToContactLink
{
    private readonly CultureInfo cultureProvider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    public GroupToContactLink()
    {
    }

    public GroupToContactLink(int contactId, int groupId, int linkTypeId)
    {
        this.ContactId = contactId;
        this.GroupId = groupId;
        this.LinkTypeId = linkTypeId;
    }

    [Required]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LinkTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LinkTypeId")]
    public virtual ContactLinkType LinkType { get; set; }

    public string CompositeKey
    {
        get
        {
            return ContactId.ToString(cultureProvider) + ":" + GroupId.ToString(cultureProvider) + ":" + LinkTypeId.ToString(cultureProvider);
        }
    }

}
```

Following is its entry from the builder in the context.  I've included **GroupToUnitLink** as well as **GroupToContactLink** because if one is wrong, the other is too.

```
builder
    .Entity<GroupToUnitLink>()
    .HasKey(c => new { c.NodeId, c.GroupId })
    .HasName("PK_Report_Link_Group_to_Units");

builder
    .Entity<GroupToContactLink>()
    .HasKey(c => new { c.ContactId, c.GroupId, c.LinkTypeId })
    .HasName("PK_Report_Link_Group_to_Contact");

builder
    .Entity<GroupToContactLink>()
    .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Group)
    .WithMany(g => g.ContactLinks);

builder
    .Entity<GroupToContactLink>()
    .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Contact)
    .WithMany(c => c.GroupLinks);

builder
    .Entity<GroupToUnitLink>()
    .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Group)
    .WithMany(g => g.UnitLinks);

builder
    .Entity<GroupToUnitLink>()
    .HasOne(gtc => gtc.Unit)
    .WithMany(c => c.GroupLinks);
```

How do I fix the error and generate more controllers?

Comment: *"because if one is wrong, the other is too"* Correct, and EF Core reports the *first* encountered issue. Anyway, the fluent code seems ok, so most likely it's just not called. Try inserting `throw new Exception("Blah");` before the posted block and try again. If you get "Blah" exception, then we'll know the code is executed and have to look somewhere else. If you get the original error, well, the code is not called and you should find why and correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I created a controller for it manually, the problem seemed to go away

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT might as well